# searching XML for value

Tags: php

I have an XML file that returns like the following:

```
<games>
 <game>
  <appID>1234</appID>
  <name>game 1</name>
 </game>
 <game>
  <appID>5678</appID>
  <name>game 2</name>
 </game>
 <game>
  <appID>9123</appID>
  <name>game 3</name>
 </game>
</games>
```

I would like my code to get the url parameter gid to $gid, search the xml for that appid and then assign $gamename if it matches in the XML. Currently it will only work when the first game is clicked. It doesn't seem to search past the first < game >.

```
$gid = (int) $_GET['gid'];
$gamespage = simplexml_load_file("http://gamepage.com/games?xml=1");
$gamelist = $gamespage->games;      
if ($gid == $gamelist->game->appID) {
$appid = $gamelist->game->appID;
$gamename = $gamelist->game->name; }
else {
echo "No game stats. <br />"; }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using an [XPath query](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$xpath = $gamespage->xpath('/games/game[appID = ' . $gid . ']/name');
if ($xpath) {
    $appid = $gid;
    $gamename = (string) $xpath[0];
} else {
    echo "No game stats. <br />";
}
```

Comment: name isnt a subset of appid though

Comment: @user1568736:  If you look at the query again,  you're notice that it's querying for a `<name>` node whose sibling `<appID>` has the value of `$gid`.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object

Comment: @user1568736:  Define "returning anything".  Are you variables not being filled up?

Comment: exactly.. after this im doing echo $gamename

Comment: This will get the name element inside a game with attribute appID.

Comment: @rcdmk:  No, it will not.  Note the lack of `@` before `appID`.